# Reading XML file line by line

Tags: xml, go

I am new to go and trying to write a script to parse multiple soap responses.

Here is a snippet of the xml snippet of the xml I am trying to parse. Its a  full SOAP response but I have just included that tags I wish to parse

```
            <Results xsi:type="AccountUser">
                <Client>
                    <ID>72rere341</ID>
                </Client>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <PartnerProperties>
                    <Name>email</Name>
                    <Value>example1@test1.com</Value>
                </PartnerProperties>
                <ID>755454475</ID>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <UserID>5fd0acfc-6crerfrgrfe6e9a675f65</UserID>
                <ActiveFlag>true</ActiveFlag>
                <Delete>0</Delete>
                <LastSuccessfulLogin>2014-11-07T16:00:46.747</LastSuccessfulLogin>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="AccountUser">
                <Client>
                    <ID>72rere5341</ID>
                </Client>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <PartnerProperties>
                    <Name>email</Name>
                    <Value>example2@test1.com</Value>
                </PartnerProperties>
                <ID>7225483</ID>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <UserID>example2@test1.com</UserID>
                <ActiveFlag>false</ActiveFlag>
                <Delete>0</Delete>
                <LastSuccessfulLogin>2015-04-29T05:01:27.85</LastSuccessfulLogin>
            </Results>
```

I would like to print each `result` on a new line.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
package main 


import (

    "os"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
    "io/ioutil"

)

type AccountUser struct {


    ParentMID string `xml:"Client>ID"`
    EmailAddress string `xml:"PartnerProperties>Value"`
    BuinessUnit string `xml:"ID"`
    UserID string `xml:"UserID"`
    Active string`xml:"ActiveFlag"`
    LastSucessfulLogin string`xml:"LastSucessfulLogin"`

}

type Email struct {

    Email string `xml:"PartnerProperties>Value"`
}


type Query struct {
    Accounts AccountUser
    AccountList []Email `xml:"PartnerProperties>Value"`
}

func (a AccountUser) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s - %s - %s", a.ParentMID, a.EmailAddress, a.UserID)
}


func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("Results.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    var q Query
    xml.Unmarshal(b, &q)

    fmt.Println(q.Accounts)
    for _, account := range q.AccountList {
        fmt.Printf("\t%s\n", account)
    }
}
```

When I run this in terminal, It returns nothing
ie.

```
-     - //just the string in the function
```

I would love pointers on how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your code  :

First is your `xml` file is not correct the correct xml file must contains parent xml like `<Data> //Yourdata here </Data>` it must be look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Data>
    <Results>
        <Client>
            <ID>72rere341</ID>
        </Client>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <PartnerProperties>
            <Name>email</Name>
            <Value>example1@test1.com</Value>
        </PartnerProperties>
        <ID>755454475</ID>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
        <UserID>5fd0acfc-6crerfrgrfe6e9a675f65</UserID>
        <ActiveFlag>true</ActiveFlag>
        <Delete>0</Delete>
        <LastSuccessfulLogin>2014-11-07T16:00:46.747</LastSuccessfulLogin>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <Client>
            <ID>72rere5341</ID>
        </Client>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <PartnerProperties>
            <Name>email</Name>
            <Value>example2@test1.com</Value>
        </PartnerProperties>
        <ID>7225483</ID>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
        <UserID>example2@test1.com</UserID>
        <ActiveFlag>false</ActiveFlag>
        <Delete>0</Delete>
        <LastSuccessfulLogin>2015-04-29T05:01:27.85</LastSuccessfulLogin>
    </Results>
</Data>
```

Second your struct `AccountUser` has a method:

```
func (a AccountUser) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s - %s - %s", a.ParentMID, a.EmailAddress, a.UserID)
}
```

To fix your problem fix the your xml file, and make your `String()` method like this :

```
func (a *AccountUser) String() string {
    return ""
}
```

And here is the working code that I have tried with the above xml file :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type AccountUser struct {
    UserID              string
    ActiveFlag          string
    LastSuccessfulLogin string
    PartnerProperties   Partner `xml:"PartnerProperties"`
}

type Partner struct {
    Name  string
    Value string
}

type Query struct {
    ResultList []AccountUser `xml:"Results"`
}

func (a *AccountUser) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s - %s - %s", a.PartnerProperties.Name, a.PartnerProperties.Value, a.UserID)
}

func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("read.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("read result = ", string(b))

    var q Query
    err = xml.Unmarshal(b, &q)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(q.ResultList[0].String())
}
```

Comment: @Data_Kid, note that you must never ever assume anything about the insignificant white space (such as like breaks) in the XML documents you process! That may break anytime due to updating or reconfiguring of the software which generates them.

Answer (score -1):

From my limited knowledge your assignment needs to be a pointer so try
 Accounts *AccountUser instead of Accounts AccountUser

You might want to supply the XML so it is easier for others to understand and show examples with.

Comment: Thanks ..now it return `<nil> will add a snippet of the xml file